# How can I make use of structlog in python rq

Tags: python-rq, structlog

In my application I am using structlog as a log system. My application also uses PythonRQ. How can I make PythonRQ to use the log system I am already using in my application so that all my application logs follows the same pattern?

Answer (score 0):

RQ is using standard library `logging` for its log output.

Therefore you can achieve that by using of the approaches listed in https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/standard-library.html